# PIC18F452 timer0 not accurate

Tags: microcontroller, pic, proteus

I am simulating a project on Proteus simulation software using this microcontroller. My issue is, I have made a 2 sec interrupt on timer0. But simulation is showing it as tooo fast (w.r.t simulation clock).

I used the Mikroelectronica Timer calculator using these settings:
[image]

The simulation schematic is as follows:
[image]

I am using MikroC pro for PIC compiler. And yes, I have double-checked the Clock frequency in the compiler, of the quartz crystal and the MCU in proteus, all are 4 MHz. I have set the crystal as XT in the compiler as well.

What could be the reason behind this inaccurate timer?

The code I'm using is as shown below:

```
int toggle1 = 0;
int toggle2 = 0;
int toggle3 = 0;
int toggle4 = 0;

void InitTimer0(){
  T0CON  = 0x84;
  TMR0H  = 0x0B;
  TMR0L  = 0xDC;
  TMR0IF_bit = 0;
  TMR0IE_bit     = 1;
}

void Interrupt() {
  if (INT0IF_bit && INT0IE_bit) {
     INT0IF_bit = 0;
     if(toggle1 == 0){
          LATC0_bit = 1;
          LATC2_bit = 0;
          toggle1 = 1;
          INTEDG0_bit = 1;         // Interrupt on rising edge on RB0
     }
     else{
          LATC0_bit = 0;
          toggle1 = 0;
          INTEDG0_bit = 0;         // Interrupt on falling edge on RB0
     }
   }
   if (INT2IF_bit && INT2IE_bit) {
     INT2IF_bit = 0;
     if(toggle2 == 0){
          LATC3_bit = 1;
          LATC2_bit = 0;
          toggle2 = 1;
          INTEDG2_bit = 1;         // Interrupt on rising edge on RB0
     }
     else{
          LATC3_bit = 0;
          toggle2 = 0;
          INTEDG2_bit = 0;         // Interrupt on falling edge on RB0
     }
   }
   if (INT1IF_bit && INT1IE_bit) {
     INT1IF_bit = 0;
     if(toggle3 == 0){
          LATC0_bit = 1;
          LATC2_bit = 0;
          toggle3 = 1;
          INTEDG1_bit = 1;         // Interrupt on rising edge on RB0
     }
     else{
          TMR0IE_bit     = 1;
          toggle3 = 0;
          INTEDG1_bit = 0;         // Interrupt on falling edge on RB0
          delay_ms(500);
          LATC0_bit = 0;
     }
   }
   if (TMR0IF_bit){
    TMR0H    = 0x0B;
    TMR0L    = 0xDC;
    if(toggle1 == 0 && toggle3 == 0)
          LATC2_bit = 0;
    if(toggle4 == 0){
         LATC4_bit = 1;
         toggle4 = 1;
    }
    else{
         LATC4_bit = 0;
         toggle4 = 0;
    }
   }

}

void main() {

  ADCON1 = 0x07;           // All digital I/O
  RBPU_bit = 0;

  TRISB = 0xFF;            // Set PB0 as input
  TRISC = 0x00;            // Set PortD as output
  PORTC = 0x00;            // Starting value for PortD

  INTEDG0_bit = 0;         // Interrupt on falling edge on RB0
  INTEDG1_bit = 0;         // Interrupt on falling edge on RB1
  INTEDG2_bit = 0;         // Interrupt on falling edge on RB2

  INT0IF_bit = 0;          // Clear INT0IF
  INT0IE_bit = 1;          // turn OFF interrupt on INT0

  INT1IF_bit = 0;          // Clear INT1IF
  INT1IE_bit = 1;          // turn OFF interrupt on INT1

  INT2IF_bit = 0;          // Clear INT2IF
  INT2IE_bit = 1;          // turn OFF interrupt on INT2

  InitTimer0();

  GIE_bit = 1;             // enable GIE

  while(1){}
}
```

Comment: Probably because you're not clearing the Timer0 Interrupt Flag in your interrupt handler. And on an unrelated note - why do you have a delay_ms() call inside your interrupt? That's begging for trouble...

Comment: Thank you that clears it. I know that delay shouldn't be there. My timers were not responding up till now, so that was a last resort. I will make a 500ms timer now for that delay purpose. Thank you!

Comment: Can someone please upvote the question. I have another related to this project but can't ask it -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you're not clearing the Timer0 Interrupt Flag in your interrupt handler.

You need to have a `TMR0IF_bit = 0;` otherwise your code will just stay stuck in the interrupt, repeating it over and over.